# Using the io Library with LuaEdit

Tags: lua

I know this is a really basic question but I've been searching the internet for days and I still can't find the answer. I've just started learning Lua and I'm going to write a text based adventure game. I'm using LuaEdit to edit my Lua code however I can't use io commands. On the Lua commandline it works if I type io.read() but it doesn't work on the editor. After searching the internet I can't find how to import the library if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't need to be imported by default. Your environment might have disabled it - but either way, seeing the error msg that happens when you try to use io.* and your knowing your editor would help.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that LuaEdit is not compiled with the I/O library. You can check that by using something like

```
if(type(io) ~= "table") then
    print("I/O not available :(");
else
    print("We have I/O!");
end
```

If it's not there by default, you could try loading it manually through the module system

```
local io = require("io");
```

But ultimately it's up to the interpreter compiled into LuaEdit whether or not this will work.

Comment: if(type(io) ~= "table") then
    print("I/O not available :(");
else
    print("We have I/O!");
end

will output We have I/O!
but the commands don't work still.

Comment: Is that the case for all io commands or just for `io.read`? Since io.read is reading user input from the console, it relies heavily on the provided terminal emulation. It could just be that LuaEdit's terminal emulator does not support this functionality.

Comment: I tried io.write() as well but it doesn't print anything either.

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator and currently only developper of LuaEdit and I can confirm to you that io.read() is not emulated in LuaEdit as of right now. I also tried the following lua code under Windows 7 and Vista and it worked without any problems when run from LuaEdit:

```
if(type(io) ~= "table") then
    print("I/O not available :(");
else
    print("We have I/O!");
end

file = io.open("c:\\test.txt", "w")
file:write("We have IO writing to disk!")
file:close()
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `os.read()` is the function you are looking for, and not `io.read()`.

If you have been coding in Lua with games like Tekkit (a Minecraft mod), then you would do `io.read()`, as that is the API they provide there.

However, when using Lua from the command line, you must use a different API, namely the functions in the `os` package.

Comment: While this answer is somewhat low quality, it appears to be on-topic, and answering the question at hand. For that reason, I have edited the post somewhat to make it more salvageable, and have decided not to try and delete it.